# Adding Angular UI Datepicker dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker

In my project I need to add dynamic amount of datepickers to the page. 
I tried to do it this way ([Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/02gmbo9N6MMQiExMA0yz?p=preview)):

Script:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);    
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.openDatePicker = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened = true;
  };

  $scope.dateOptions = {
    formatYear: "yy",
    startingDay: 1,
    format: "shortDate"
  };

  $scope.details = [{
    "parameterValue": "2015-08-12"
  }, {
    "parameterValue": "2015-08-12"
  }, {
    "parameterValue": "2015-08-12"
  }, {
    "parameterValue": "2015-08-12"
  }];
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.3/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.3.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="detailsForm" novalidate ng-submit="submitForm(detailsForm.$valid)">
      <div ng-repeat="item in details" class="input-group">
        <input ng-model="item.parameterValue" type="text" class="form-control" id="datePickerItem" datepicker-popup="shortDate" 
        is-open="opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" current-text="Today" clear-text="Clear" close-text="Close" ng-readonly="false" />
        <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDatePicker($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I try to open one datepicker, all of them are opened (logically, as they share the same `$scope.opened` variable). Also when I close them and try to open them again, nothing happens.

Is there a elegant way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of your datepickers have `id="datePickerItem"`.

The `id` attribute *must* be unique in html. Try this instead:

```
id="datePickerItem_{{$index}}"
```

This will add the `ng-repeat`'s current index to the id, so you can be relatively certain your id's are unique. This should also prevent all the datepickers from opening at the same time.

Also, you're using one and the same `opened` variable for all datepickers.

Try this instead:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in details" class="input-group">
    <input ng-model="item.parameterValue" type="text" class="form-control" 
        id="datePickerItem_{{$index}}" datepicker-popup="shortDate" 
        is-open="opened[$index]" datepicker-options="dateOptions" current-text="Today"
        clear-text="Clear" close-text="Close" ng-readonly="false" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDatePicker($event, $index)">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
```

And:

```
$scope.opened = [];
$scope.openDatePicker = function($event, index) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    $scope.opened[index] = true;
};
```

Just make sure you set `$scope.opened[index]` to `false`, in case you close the datepicker.

Comment: You are right, they all have the same id. I tried to add {{$index}} but unfortunately it makes no difference. I think it's caused by the '$scope.opened' variable.

Comment: @MartinSlezák: I added some more to my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$scope.open = function($event,opened) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();
        $scope[opened] = true;
    };
```

and in your html

```
ng-click="open($event, 'nameOfYourModel')"
```

Answer (score 0):

why not bind `opened` on the `repeat object`?

like:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in details" class="input-group">
    <input ng-model="item.parameterValue" type="text" class="form-control" 
        id="datePickerItem_{{$index}}" datepicker-popup="shortDate" 
        is-open="item['opened']" datepicker-options="dateOptions" current-text="Today"
        clear-text="Clear" close-text="Close" ng-readonly="false" />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openDatePicker($event, item)">
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.openDatePicker = function($event, item) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();

    if(item.opened){
        item.opened = !item.opened;
    } else{
        item.opened = true;
    }
};
```