# jquery ui directive creating issue with angularjs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-directive

```
lostBaggageApp.directive('calendar',['$timeout', function($timeout) {
return {
restrict: 'A',
require: 'ngModel',
link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
    element.datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        maxDate: '0',
        onSelect: function (date) {
          alert(date);
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(date);
        }
    });
  }
```

There are multiple date fields on a page, and applying ng-repeat creating problem with datepicked field only. first date field is accepting value and if want to change into other date field its value is reflecting on first date field.

Comment: You should give different IDs to your datepickers. I think this is what you need - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31959002/adding-angular-ui-datepicker-dynamically

Comment: thanks :) it works...i don't think of id parameter....blunder.